# Custom Like count with JavaScript, PHP, MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, crud

Hoping you can help me.

**My Goal**

1. Creating a custom Like(♥) button with a counter.
2. Store (INSERT) onclick() output value to MySQL
3. Increment (UPDATE) stored value by one(+1)
4. Retrieve (READ) lastest incremented value from MySQL and display on web page

**What I have working**

I have JavaScript outputting the value of '1' onclick.

**My issue**

Storing the JavaScript value on a database so it increments by 1 for every user click. I'm a bit suck with this. Any help is highly appreciated!

**THE PROBLEM CODE:**

HTML:

```
<div class="heart" id="like" onclick="onClick()">
    <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
// Heart Like counts
var clicks = 0;
var hasClicked = false;
    function onClick() 
    {
     if (!hasClicked) 
      {
       clicks += 1;
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = clicks;
          hasClicked = true; 
      };
        
    };
```

PHP (Connection File to DB)

```js
<?php
//Opens connection to MySQL sever.
$severname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$dbname = 'db_Portfolio';


//Creating connection to DB
$conn = mysql_connect($severname, $username, $password);

// Check connection.
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Status of connection. 
echo "Connected to database successfully.";
?>
```

**MySQL:**

```js
CREATE TABLE `Like_Count` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Likes` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Likes` (`Likes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the database schema or other table design. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: `UPDATE table set like=like+1 where id = XXX`

Comment: What is not working? Any console errors?

Comment: @lockedz Everything is working not sure what to do next using PHP CRUD.

Comment: Now send data to a server.

Comment: @zerkms This is the part I am stuck and need some guidance.

Comment: To send the data back to the sever, you can use the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function, if using the jQuery is an option :)

Comment: Can't you pass the `click` value to an `<input type="hidden">`, get it into PHP and do an INSERT INTO Like_Count (Likes)
VALUES ('$php_likes')"; ?

Comment: You shouldn't believe the front-end, so you should check if someone had clicked it backstage.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Like_Count` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Like_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `Like_count` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Likes` (`Like_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the `user` table :

```
CREATE TABLE `Like_Count` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `User_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `Like_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

so everytime someone clicks, check in `user` table to see if he has clicked. If not, update the `count` table with the `Like_id` you find in the `user` table to get the record in `count` table.

You'd better do the click action by using JavaScript and using PHP for checking and database works.